# Get PC's Monitor Information Using .NET / WMI

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, monitor

Is there anyway using WMI/.Net to grab monitor information such as Manufacturer, Serial Number, Monitor Size etc.?

Using a script is an option as well, or can I query the registry directly to get this information?

`SELECT * FROM   Win32_DesktopMonitor` doesn't really return any useful information for me in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try this

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxAnderson95/Get-Monitor-Information/master/Get-Monitor.ps1

Cheers

Comment: @TamirVered ...and the first link looks broken.

Comment: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rzander/archive/2009/03/30/wmi-provider-to-list-the-monitors-serialnr-and-model-name.aspx not found

Comment: The script was added over 8 years ago, but I have updated with a new script from github. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

Hey, I use this tool for a lot of my WMI work, especially when prototyping and creating POCs....

[Microsoft WMI Code Generator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)

This tool is great for creating quick console app code for any wmi query or method invocation in both C# and VB.NET

```
try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor"); 

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_DesktopMonitor instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
```

The code above will get you the make and model of the monitor.

Comment: FYI, Win32_DesktopMonitor doesn't appear to get all monitors. WMIMonitorID, from root\WMI, appears to get more/all.

Answer (score 2):

That select query should give you what you want.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(VS.85).aspx) is the documentation which contains the details of the query.

Then you could do something like this:

```
    public void GetMonitorDetails()
    {
       using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor")
       {
          foreach(ManagementObject currentObj in searcher.Get())
          {
             String name = currentObj("Name").ToString();
             String device_id = currentObj("DeviceID").ToString();
             // ...
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: That's the query I listed in the question that doesn't work :)!

Comment: It doesn't give me a lot of the information I'm looking for (Serial #, Monitor Size, It says Monitor Manufacturer but it's value is : <Standard Monitior Types> which isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: @snow : That could be due to the currently installed monitor you have on your machine... Have a look in device manager to see what the details on your currently installed monitor and compare.

Comment: Win32_DesktopMonitor doesn't list all the monitors that are connection. Currently I have 10 monitors connected and running properly to my PC but this query lists only 4 of them.

Comment: @RoniTovi 10 monitors ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Yes, it was a videowall application using only 1 pc.

Comment: How connected 10 monitors to motherboard? using DVI, HDMI, VGA ?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/03/use-powershell-to-discover-multi-monitor-information.aspx), combined with the answer below about the WMI management tool had my answer.  Here is the code that returns your monitor resolutions.

```
try {                 
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
            "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams");    

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
            Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Debug.WriteLine("WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams instance");
            Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Debug.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["SupportedDisplayFeatures"]);
        }
    } catch (ManagementException e) {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
    }
```

In my case, I'm still stuck, because it is returning the "scaled down" resolution of each monitor.  One of mine is a 4K display, being reported as 2560x1440.