# Detect if a hardware device is working or not in C#

Tags: c#, hardware, low-level-api

Is it possible in C# to detect that any hardware attached to computer has stopped working!
If yes then how?

Comment: Depends on the hardware. This needs more data in order to be answerable.

Comment: I want to create a general software.That will intimate user about any hardware(Periphrel) attached to computer failure.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of hardware, [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells you lots about the hardware. Specifically, here is a [list of hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that WMI can provide information about.

Comment: Can you reference any example.

Comment: Search this site, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477077/get-pcs-monitor-information-using-net-wmi